# ASP.NET MVC ViewBag return null

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Why `@Html.LabelFor(model => model.data, ((string)ViewBag.id))` 
return in `public ActionResult Index(Data item)` null instead of `100`. How to fix this?

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewBag.id = "100";
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(Data item)
    {
        return View();
    }
```

Index.cshtml

```
@model TestForm.Models.Data
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

@using(@Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.data, ((string)ViewBag.id))
    <input type="submit"/>
}
```

Comment: `LabelFor()` does not generate a form control. Very unclear what you trying to do, but you need to set the value of `model.data=100;` in the controller before you pass the model to the view, and then in the view use `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.data)` (and remove your `ViewBag`)

Comment: @StephenMuecke I think it's  enough for the answer.

Comment: You do nned to unbox the string since viewbag is already string @Html.LabelFor(model => model.data, ViewBag.id)

Answer (score 0):

> Why @Html.LabelFor(model => model.data, ((string)ViewBag.id)) return in public ActionResult Index(Data item) null instead of 100

You are never are setting the value in that method. If you want it to show in the label after that method, then you need to add `ViewBag.id = "100";` to the method.

If you are trying to have that set as your default value, then you are really creating your form incorrectly. It should be a `<%= Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.[fieldname], ViewBag.id))%>`

This would then be posted back in your `Data item` object and be set. Note, you have to change the [fieldname]